# IE table height not stretching to max possible

Tags: html, css, html-table

Could not find any good answer from the forum. 
I have a table inside a td situation which I cannot avoid somehow. IE ignores the table's 'height: 100%' style and take the minimum possible height. While the ff extends the table height to fit in td

Run this fiddle in IE 8 or up. I expect the red line to extend the entire height of the text. 
http://jsfiddle.net/VKG3f/

```
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<head><style>
.line
{
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    min-height: 10px;
    max-width: 5px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-color: red;
}
.text
{
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    max-width: 100px;
}
body
{
    margin-top: 8px;
}

</style></head>
<body ><div id="d1">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary=""><tbody>
<tr>
 <td style="height: 100%">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="" style="height: 100%;  overflow:scroll;">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="line">
      <div class="line">
       <span class=""></span>
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
 <td>
  <div class="text">
   <a title="Current Step: This is a very long text which might even go to six lines and is done to check wrapping" 
   href="#">This is a very long text which might even go to six lines and is done to check wrapping</a>
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>

</tbody></table></div></div></div></form></div></body></html>
```

Comment: [**Fiddle Site**](http://jsfiddle.net/) is not compatible with IE8, Don't have IE 9 :(

Comment: Op seems to want to have same height for `<td style="height: 100%">`

and

`<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="" style="height: 100%;  overflow:scroll;">`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `height:100%` to `body,html` and for parent div

```
body, html
{
    margin-top: 8px; height:100%
}
table, #d1{
    height:100%
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VKG3f/1/)**

Comment: This extends the red line to the entire body. I wanted it take up the height the text takes.